# Cant validate facebook og meta after updating to https

Tags: facebook, ssl, https, meta, yoast

I have recently apdated my site from http to https. The system is using wordpress, and posts are all using Yoast pluging for seating the information for facebook posts. After I updated to https, I lost all my facebook information. I already redirected old links and updated my source code two. Yoast does write meta tags with https, but it doest seams to have any efect. Cant find where is the mistake.

https://aoriente.com/news/688/

For this link, yoast does write the following tags on my header:

```
<meta property="og:locale" content="pt_BR" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Guia prático do motociclista no Vietnam: Viagens!!!! - Ao Oriente" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Como viajar de moto com seguranca pelo interior do Vietnam. Dicas sobre equipamentos, estradas, manobras, etc..." />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://aoriente.com/news/688/" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Ao Oriente" />
<meta property="article:publisher" content="https://www.facebook.com/aooriente/" />
<meta property="article:tag" content="aventura" />
<meta property="article:tag" content="viagem" />
<meta property="article:section" content="Vietnam" />
<meta property="article:published_time" content="2019-01-14T12:46:30+00:00" />
<meta property="article:modified_time" content="2019-01-16T16:03:24+00:00" />
<meta property="og:updated_time" content="2019-01-16T16:03:24+00:00" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="937743383101636" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://aoriente.com/castelo/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/DSCN7631-1024x768.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://aoriente.com/castelo/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/DSCN7631-1024x768.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1024" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="768" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Como viajar de moto com seguranca pelo interior do Vietnam. Dicas sobre equipamentos, estradas, manobras, etc..." />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Guia prático do motociclista no Vietnam: Viagens!!!! - Ao Oriente" />
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@AoOriente" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://aoriente.com/castelo/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/DSCN7631.jpg" />
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@AoOriente" />
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Faoriente.com%2Fnews%2F688%2F: _“Can't validate SSL Certificate. Either it is self-signed (which will cause browser warnings) or it is invalid.”_

Comment: https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=aoriente.com: _“The certificate is not trusted in all web browsers. You may need to install an Intermediate/chain certificate to link it to a trusted root certificate. Learn more about this error. You can fix this by following Sectigo's Certificate Installation Instructions for your server platform (use these instructions for InstantSSL). Pay attention to the parts about Intermediate certificates.”_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its was a problem due to a bad intermediate as cited on comments. I contacted my host and they fixed the error.

“The certificate is not trusted in all web browsers. You may need to install an Intermediate/chain certificate to link it to a trusted root certificate. Learn more about this error. You can fix this by following Sectigo's Certificate Installation Instructions for your server platform (use these instructions for InstantSSL). Pay attention to the parts about Intermediate certificates.” –